# How to convert documentation site to book for printing

Tags: conversion, html, printed

lets say i have a typical documentation website like https://docs.kernel.org/ but locally. It may or may not consist of frames, often a frame with the table of contents and a frame with actual documentation.

I want to convert a website like this to a printable book format. This would involve...

- establishing a map of the website by parsing the table of contents and also following links on the documentation pages itself, augmenting the table of contents if information is to be found linked in the actual documentation text that are not include in the tabel of contents but are inside the documentation site domain.
- use this table of contents to establish a chapter structure
- combine the to toc and invididual html page files into an book format

Is there software that does such a thing, or how should i go about that?

Comment: Welcome to ebooks.SE!
I general you can increase the chances of getting a good answer by explaining your problem statement with a minimal, but reproduceble example.
Also adding details about what you have tried so far helps to narrow down the solution space.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.